# MagicalRecord not saving

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I wonder why my Core Data stop to save changes. In fact, code above worked hours ago. When i try to print out an error, it print `(null)`. Code below is custom method for `NSManagedObjectSubclass`:

```
-(void)bindWithModel:(MenuAPIModel*)model{

    self.basketId = [model.basketId integerValue];
    self.coreId = [model.itemId integerValue];
    self.name = [model name];
    self.orderId = [model.orderId integerValue];
    self.payedFrom = [model payedFrom];
    self.persons = [model persons];
    self.price = [model.price integerValue];
    self.price3 = [model.price3 integerValue];
    self.price12 = [model.price12 integerValue];
    self.status = [model status];

     [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveOnlySelfWithCompletion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSLog(@"error %@", error.localizedDescription);

}];
```

Error is null and `contextDidSave` is YES. But when i try to access entity it prints null, and SQL table is an empty. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `bindWithModel` method is in `NSManagedObject` subclass. If so, then you should use `managedObjectContext` property from this class rather then `MR_defaultContext`:

```
[self.managedObjectContext  MR_saveOnlySelfWithCompletion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError * _Nullable error) { (...) }];
```

Previously it was working probably because context from `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]` was the same as `self.managedObjectContext`.

Comment: Thank for your help but it actually did save and data exist. Problem is - I don't know where it stores data. Database file in sandbox is empty

Comment: If database file in sandbox is empty then it means that data was not saved. How do you validate that data was saved? Maybe try to fetch those data using `MR_defaultContext` (or some new context) in some other place an check for sure that this data exist.

Comment: I can validate it by logging data in console , and it's correct

Comment: but from which source are you taking those data? If contexts of this data are the same then you will see all data. Maybe try to kill the app and open again if data are still available then problem is somewhere else :(

Comment: when I try to log path to file it print other file named CoreData.sqlite but I can't find it in finder even when I make hidden files visible